# How do I check if my variable value is in a pre-defined list of static values in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, list, variables

How do I check if my variable value is in a pre-defined list of static values in VBA? I am a beginner at this, so please keep it really simple!

My variable is called RowNum and has a particular value
I want to see if it appears in a pre-defined static list of values (e.g. 15, 22, 35).

I can only find more complicated examples and I'm getting lost in it all!

Something to do with arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-defined static list"? It'd be preferable if you could share the code creating this list.

Comment: `Dim m As Variant: m = Application.Match(RowNum, Array(15, 22, 35),0)` then test with `If Not IsError(m)` to see if you got a match.

Answer (score 1):

I think *Application.Match* is the wrong approach because the second argument is an array of cells and no list.
Here are three solutions (*myRowNumCheck0, myRowNumCheck1, myRowNumCheck2*):

```
Option Explicit

Public Const relevantRowNumsAsString As String = "#15#22#35#"  ' your predefined list seperated by #
                                                               ' neccessary for myRowNumCheck1 and myRowNumCheck2
Sub Test()

Debug.Print "myRowNumCheck0: " & myRowNumCheck1(4) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(22) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(35) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(55)
Debug.Print "myRowNumCheck1: " & myRowNumCheck1(4) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(22) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(35) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(55)
Debug.Print "myRowNumCheck2: " & myRowNumCheck1(4) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(22) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(35) & " " & myRowNumCheck1(55)
End Sub

Function myRowNumCheck0(numberToCheck As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim myArray(3) As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    myArray(0) = 15
    myArray(1) = 22
    myArray(2) = 35
    myRowNumCheck0 = False
    
    For k = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        If numberToCheck = myArray(k) Then
            myRowNumCheck0 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next k

End Function
Function myRowNumCheck1(numberToCheck As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim numberToCheckString As String
    Dim k As Integer
    
    myArray = Split(relevantRowNumsAsString, "#", -1, vbTextCompare)
    myRowNumCheck1 = False
    
    For k = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(numberToCheck) = myArray(k) Then
            myRowNumCheck1 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next k

End Function
Function myRowNumCheck2(numberToCheck As Integer) As Boolean
    
    If InStr(0, "#" & numberToCheck & "#", relevantRowNumsAsString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        myRowNumCheck2 = True
    Else
        myRowNumCheck2 = False
    End If
End Function
```

Calling *Test* produces the following output:

```
myRowNumCheck0: False True True False
myRowNumCheck1: False True True False
myRowNumCheck2: False True True False
```

If your list has only a few elements I would prefer *myRowNumCheck2* because you avoid an array. For *myRowNumCheck2* it is important to start and close *relevantRowNumsAsString* with the delimiter #.
You must ensure, that the characters between the delimiters consists only of digits (0 to 9).